# Stopping .pyc and .pyo been generated

Tags: python

I have an rpm which contains a python script. When the rpm is installed on a server it creates .pyc and .pyo files. Is there a flag I can place inside my script which will stop the generation of these files. I can't change the install script. The script(Python) will be ran by a user at a later time.

I have tried `#!/usr/bin/python -B` but it didn't appear to work.
I have seen `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` but I am unsure if this will work as the script will not be run during install time.

Python version is 2.6.6

Any help would be appreciated.

Note:
Thanks for the replies so far. The files appear to get created at the same time the script is placed on the server. I assume the installer is doing this. The .pyc and pyo files are just for the script itself. 
Example:`scriptname.py ,scriptname.pyc, scriptname.pyo`

It appears as if it is happening during the creation of the rpm. Could Maven be generating these files and if so is there a way to stop it packaging them in the rpm?

Comment: did you check whether these `.pyc` and `.pyo` files are generated during installation or not? If yes, you'll have to mess with the installer providing some flags to it or by running some post-install script that deletes them.

Comment: There's nothing you can place inside the Python code, because whatever you place there won't run until after it's been compiled, which is when the `.pyc` file gets created.

Comment: @abarnert Actually if you add the shebang line to the main executable the shell, when launching the program with `./program` or by simply using `program` if it's in the `PATH`, will use the selected interpreter passing the given command line so it *will* work (just checked). It doesn't work if you place it only in the modules you are importing and you run the main program calling the python interpreter directly.

Comment: If the script doesn't need stdin, you can do the heredoc hack: write a shell script that starts with `#!/bin/sh` then `python -B << END_PYTHON`, then all the Python code, then `END_PYTHON`…

Comment: Have you tried setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` somewhere in your system configuration?

Comment: Can you explain _what_ `.pyc` files are created, and _when_ they're created? Is it `.pyc` files for the script itself, other modules included with the script, other modules anywhere on the system that the script references? Are they created at install time, or when the script is run by a user at a later time, or both, or …?

Comment: From your edit, it sounds like you have a post-install script that explicitly does something like `python -m compile` on the installed file to generate a .pyc file. If you don't want that, just don't do that. And if you can't change the install script, and the install script is what's doing this, then you really can't fix it.

Comment: I think it might be maven which is creating the files when it creates the rpm.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the script imports other modules, and you get `.pyc` files for those other modules (not the script itself) when "The script(Python) will be ran by a user at a later time", and you want to stop that, that's just:

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = False
```

You say:

> I have seen sys.dont_write_bytecode = True but I am unsure if this will work as the script will not be run during install time.

That's fine. If the script isn't run at install time, it won't generate any bytecode in the first place, so that's not a problem. When it's run later by the user, this will make it not generate `.pyc` files.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.dont_write_bytecode).

---

If, on the other hand, your problem is that the installer is doing something that pre-generates `.pyc` files for the script or all of the modules the script needs, then nothing you do in the script is going to fix that; you just need to remove the part of the installer that does that.